# Where to put controller-wide accessible objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like give access to the (currently logged-in) user object to all controllers, and views, in my application. For example, I want to put the users name in my "sidebar" partial, but don't know how to access the user object since that is stored in an other controller. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) helper method. You could define a view model which will contain all the necessary information you would like to show about the currently logged in user (like his username for example) and then have a controller action which will use the User property of the controller to populate this view model and pass it to a corresponding partial view. Then inside your master page you would include this information using the Html.Action helper:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    @Html.Action("Index", "Users")
</div>
```

which will invoke the `Index` action of the `UsersController`:

```
public class UsersController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserViewModel model = ...
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. But does that mean that I'll have to generate a own method + partial view every time to render a name or link?

Comment: @user772945, in my answer I've taken as an example the case of showing the currently logged in username on all pages. I don't really understand what you mean by *rendering a name or link*? Are you talking about an AJAX to a controller action that will update a portion of the DOM? It will really depend on what you are trying to achieve. There many different techniques in MVC suitable for different scenarios.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about AJAX - what I mean is: what If i want to display a "Edit my personal data" link a few lines below the username (and the link should point to /users/edit/id)? Should I then repeat the procedure and create a partial which only "outputs" a link?

Comment: @user772945, to generate a link you would use the `Html.ActionLink` helper. If you want this link to display some partial view, well, you would create a controller action serving this partial view and you will AJAXify this link. In the success callback of the AJAX request you will update the corresponding part of the DOM (the location where you want the results to be displayed) with the result of the partial view returned by the server.